# SMTP Verification using PHP EHLO

Tags: php, email, smtp, verification

I'm trying to do email verification and I can't seem to get it going.  At present it would make the connection to the domain but after that it seems to time out.  Does anyone know why this is? It seems to be hanging here:

```
$res=fgets($connection, "EHLO $mydomain\n");
```

Would anyone be able to inform me as to why this is? My code is below:

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))

{

 // Could get this from the php ini? 
  $from="xxxx@xxxx-int.net";
 $to=$_POST['email'];
 $subject="Test";
 $message="Testing";
 list($me,$mydomain) = split("@",$from); 

 // Now look up the mail exchangers for the recipient 
 list($user,$domain) = split("@",$to,2); 
 if(getmxrr($domain,$mx,$weight) == 0)  return FALSE; 

 // Try them in order of lowest weight first 
 array_multisort($mx,$weight); 
 $success=0; 

 foreach($mx as $host) { 
  // Open an SMTP connection 
  $connection = fsockopen ($host, 25, $errno, $errstr, 1); 
  if (!$connection) 
    continue; 
  $res=fgets($connection); 
echo $res;
  if(substr($res,0,3) != "220") echo $res;

  // Introduce ourselves 
  fputs($connection, "EHLO $mydomain\n"); 
  $res=fgets($connection); 
echo $res;
  if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") echo $res; 

  // Envelope from 
  fputs($connection, "MAIL FROM: $from\n"); 
  $res=fgets($connection); 
echo $res; 
  if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") echo $res; 

  // Envelope to 
  fputs($connection, "RCPT TO: $to\n"); 
  $res=fgets($connection); 
echo $res; 
  if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") echo $res;

  // The message 
  fputs($connection, "DATA\n"); 
  $res=fgets($connection); 
echo $res; 
  if(substr($res,0,3) != "354") echo $res;

  // Send To:, From:, Subject:, other headers, blank line, message, and finish 
  // with a period on its own line. 
  fputs($connection, "To: $to\nFrom: $from\nSubject: $subject\n$message\n.\n"); 
  $res=fgets($connection); 
echo $res; 
  if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") echo $res;

  // Say bye bye 
  fputs($connection,"QUIT\n"); 
  $res=fgets($connection); 
echo $res; 
  if(substr($res,0,3) != "221") echo $res;

  // It worked! So break out of the loop which tries all the mail exchangers. 
  $success=1; 
  break; 
 } 
 // Debug for if we fall over - uncomment as desired 
 // print $success?"Mail sent":"Failure: $res\n"; 
 if($connection) { 
  if($success==0) fputs($connection, "QUIT\n"); 
  fclose ($connection); 
 } 
 return $success?TRUE:FALSE; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own SMTP interface when you could just use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer and get on with your day?

Comment: this *could* be a block from an early talker detection system. Your code doesn't seem to handle multiline banners. What is the content of $res before you send your EHLO ?

Comment: cause im tryin to get it to the point of rcpt to: and if it produces an error 550 then dont allow it do to something, otherwise continue if rcpt to: is 250

Comment: @Gryphius - im not completely sure? i would assume it would be the connection details of the domain

Comment: you print it out before you do the EHLO, so you should see it...? also you could test by simply telnettig to the target host and check if the banner has multiple lines

Comment: @Gryphius when i run it i get the following:

Comment: 220 BAY0-MC1-F5.Bay0.hotmail.com Sending unsolicited commercial or bulk e-mail to Microsoft's computer network is prohibited. Other restrictions are found at http://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/anti-spam.mspx. Tue, 12 Nov 2013 06:53:27 -0800 
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\guest\test.php on line 140

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  fputs($connection, "EHLO $mydomain\n");
```

you only send line feeds at the end, but [smtp rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.8) requires CRLF. This causes your script to "hang" because the email server will not respond to your invalid line ending.
you'd have to change this to

```
  fputs($connection, "EHLO $mydomain\r\n");
```

etc.

Please note that email validation will NOT WORK in many cases, even if you get your script to talk RFC compliant SMTP. Many servers simply accept (and later bounce) all messages to invalid recipients. Others do recipient verification at the data stage instead of rcpt to (exchange 2013..*sigh*) etc etc.

Comment: i done this and it gets past the ehlo command, however it would ignore my mail from:, rcpt to:, and data and just go straight to the quit command.  the message im getting when i echo the $res is:


220 net-isp.net ESMTP MailCleaner (Community Edition 2012.5) Tue, 12 Nov 2013 15:45:13 +0000 
250-net-isp.net Hello host217-45-150-185.in-addr.btopenworld.com [217.45.150.185] 
250-SIZE 52428800 
250-8BITMIME 
250-PIPELINING 
250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 
250-STARTTLS

Comment: sorry, no more help from me. you're trying to send mails to third party servers from a blacklisted IP using a completely broken PHP script which you basically copied from an 11 year old comment on the php fsockopen manual page... Please get familiar with the SMTP protocol and the code you're trying to use first, then ask again.